# Indexing a column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Imagine that I have a column starting at B1 to B20. If one of the cells contain a text (not a specific value) I want to generate a list in C1 to xxx (depending on how many value if find).

Example: 
Text in column B1 looks like:

B1 -> test,

B5 -> test 2,

B14 -> test 3.

Then the column C1 generates:

C1 -> test,

C2 -> test 2,

C3 -> test 3

Is that possible?

Comment: Can you show a sample of your data? Are there gaps in your data, or non-text values or all text-values but other than what you want to list..... so many question. Try to be clear. Have a look at [ask] a question with a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you want but you could try something like this:

[image]

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/IfAprVy.png

Column 1 is the data column. I want column 2 to order it from top to bottom.

Comment: If you did not put all the info in your original question, then you should do that.